# Phases order in "Catan: Cities & Knights"

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

According game rules, each player can perform any action (building, trading, knight activation, etc.) in any order during her/his turn.

Can an action type be done more than once in the same turn?

Example: It's John's turn:

1. he activates a knight
2. he builds a settlement on an harbor with 3:1 commercial ratio
3. he uses such 3:1 change ratio to exchange resources with the bank
4. he trades with othere players
5. he builds a road
6. he activates another knight

I have that conundrum since in the classic Catan, the trading phase and the building one are strictly separated and you cannot mix them up (you can just if you use advanced rules).

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your question! Could you please condense this to a Minimal Example? i.e. if I understand your question correctly, you could remove steps 2, 3, and 4 entirely, so since they're there, a) I worry that I *don't* understand the question correctly, and b) the essence of your question is lost in irrelevant details.

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminCosman for your kind welcome. Points 2,3 and 4 aim at underlying the usage of a resource you've just built in the turn. But ok, you are right, they are not strictly necessary for the example. Do you mind if I leave them in the question for understanding if I can use that new resource in the same turn?

Comment: The question is quite understandable as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can take the same kind of action at multiple points in your turn. The relevant rule is:

> You may do any or all of the following in any order:
>
> – Trade resources and/or commodities with the bank and/or other players.
>
> – Build roads, settlements, cities, knights, city walls, and/ or city improvements.
>
> – Activate, promote, and/or perform actions with your knights.
>
> – Play any number of progress cards.

This *could* be read to mean that each of those four bullet points are "phases" that can happen only once each in an order of your choice, but we can infer that the intended meaning is the more permissive one by this later rule:

> **Trading and Building**
>
> In Cities & Knights, you are allowed to build and trade any number of times and in any order. You do not need to finish all of your trading before you begin your building.

Comment: Perfect! And can we leverage a settlement we've just built on an harbor with a more convenient commercial ratio?

Comment: Yep. The trading rule is just "If you have a settlement or a city on a harbor..."; it doesn't say "If you had a settlement or a city on a harbor since the beginning of the turn...".